# AngularJS View does not update after model update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `<div>` on my page for alert message:

```
<div ng-controller="PercentageOverrideController as ctrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="alert.html">
    <div class="alert" style="background-color:#fa39c3;color:white" role="alert">
      <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
  </script>
  <uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>
  <button type="button" class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

In my Angular controller I have a variable `$scope.alerts = [ ]` and function which pushes a new alert message to an array:

```
$scope.showSuccess = function(){
  $scope.alerts.push({type: 'success', msg: 'Threshold Overrided'});
};

$scope.showError = function(){
  $scope.alerts.push({type: 'danger', msg: 'Error has been happened'});
};
```

After I make a request and get a response, I check in debug mode that the function was invoked and that a new value was added to the array. However it does not appear on my page.

I have a test button in my `div`:

```
<button type="button" class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
```

If I press this button, the alert appears on the page. If I try to invoke the same function:

```
$scope.addAlert = function() {
  $scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
};
```

within the code:

```
$scope.showSuccess = function(){
  $scope.alerts.push({type: 'success', msg: 'Threshold Overrided'});
  $scope.addAlert();
};
```

but the alert does not appear on page.

I assume that I should trigger somehow the view to show that update on page. What do you think guys?
Thank you!

Comment: Try going simpler... Add in a simple {{alerts}} in your HTML and see if anything changes.

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: When I use {{alerts}} it shows only objects which were added by button. Hmm. need to check that. Thank you!

Comment: thats because alerts is an array.

Comment: How are `$scope.showError` and `$scope.showSuccess` invoked? As the answers have alluded to, it is likely that the model is being modified outside of the Angular digest cycle, which will cause this kind of issue.

Comment: Thank you all guys!
When I invoked my function from different places(from success function and button), I got that my array with messages is in different scopes. Then I found my fault: I put div with button and container for messages in one div, and form with submit was in other div. They both used the same Controller, however they were in different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.apply()`

```
$scope.showSuccess = function(){
  $scope.alerts.push({type: 'success', msg: 'Threshold Overrided'});
  $scope.addAlert();
  $scope.apply();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run a digest loop.

```
$scope.$apply()
```

or alternatively

```
$scope.$digest()
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<div ng-controller="PercentageOverrideController as ctrl">`

try `<div ng-controller="PercentageOverrideController">`